# add id to condition if($("input:radio[value=pakiet1]").is(":checked"))

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, conditional-statements

```
if($("input:radio[value=pakiet1]").is(":checked"))
```

I want to add another criterion: id

Neither

```
if($("input:radio[id=idea1][value=pakiet1]").is(":checked"))
```

nor

```
if($("input:radio[value=pakiet1;id=idea1]").is(":checked"))
```

works. How to do that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that just using '#idea1' won't? Are you trying to write an "or"?

Comment: Separate selectors with comma.

Answer (score 0):

If the input has an ID, you can refer to it that way. In which case, try

`if ($('#idea1').is(':checked')) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer it by name, and access it using the below function.

```
     if ($('input[name=gender]:checked').length > 0) {
       // do something here
      }
```